# How to create custom static analysis rule that checks a specific property value

Tags: static-analysis, fxcop, rules

I would like to use the FXCop introspection API to create a custom rule that verifies the following:

in MethodA, the code sets a property B on a static class C to value D :

void MethodA()
{
    C.B=D;
}

how can I write this?
also how can I debug through a rule?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question isn't exactly clear to me. Is this a pattern you want to have FxCop report as a problem?

For your second question:

- Start up your custom FxCop rules project in Visual Studio.
- Start FxCop and add your custom FxCop rules dll (the one you built in debug configuration)
- Now go to Tools -> Attach to Process... (ctrl alt P)
- Choose FxCop.exe
- Run the analysis

Visual Studio will break on the break points you have set.

I found [this](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html) site to be quite extensive.